# What does 0x%4x mean in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I think I understand what % means in python. But I don't understand what the 0x and 4x means. Any help is great even if you just link the documentation for %.

Here is the example code:

```
wr.write('Base Addr=0x%4x' % 
           (Base_Address))
```

Comment: I couldn't find it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%4x` is a way of formatting a number in hexidecimal

```
>>> '%4x' % 0xffff
'ffff'
>>> '%4x' % 0xffa1
'ffa1'
```

The leading `0x` will just be literal characters that end up carrying over into the string.

```
>>> '0x%4x' % 0xffa1
'0xffa1'
```

The `4` specifies the minimum width (smaller output will be padded on the left with spaces):

```
>>> '%4x' % 0xff
'  ff'
```

Comment: Thank You. I understand it now!